# Using Time Machine with Virtualization (Parallels, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc...)

Tags: time-machine, backup, vmware, parallels-desktop, virtualbox

Since a single small change to a VM file should (I think) cause the entire multi-gigabyte file to be backed up *again*, are there any ideas I can use to more effectively backup my machine?

Assume that I only need one copy of a VM, and changes made to the VM don't matter.

For example:

- Backup the VM using time machine once, then exclude the folder that contains all the VMs
- Exclude the VM's altogether and manually back up the VMs
- Let Apple's software do it's thing, it will be effective at managing the disk space

Comment: Do you want this to be a very general discussion or perhaps focus on one disk image format. As the one answer shows, you can have snapshots that reduce the monolithic nature of a VM's drive.

Answer (score 4):

Parallels has a [specific setting](http://kb.parallels.com/8827) to optimize its VMs for backup by Time Machine and prevent backing up unchanged data.

> To enable improved integration with Time Machine, please go to Virtual Machine Configuration, choose Options and hit Backup.
>
> Select "Optimize for Time Machine" in SmartGuard menu.

Similarly, VMWare Fusion has [some support for Time Machine](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2011/12/backing-up-your-virtual-machine-with-time-machine.html), which appears to involve turning on snapshots.

Answer (score 3):

"... I store all of my virtual machines on a sparsebundle disk image. This is a mounted filesystem that seamlessly breaks up the filesystem into many 8MB files. That level of granularity keeps my TM backups small. For example, I have three individual VMs stored on a single sparsebundle volume. They currently occupy 3012 individual 8MB "bundle" files. The last time I used those VMs, I ran software updates on all of them. A total of 118 of those 8MB files changed as a result of the updates, so the TM backup was 944MB. If they were not on a sparsebundle volume, the TM backup would have been about 24GB.

I use Parallels, but the same concept should apply to any application that creates and frequently updates very large files. Use Disk Utility to create the sparsebundle volume."

Source: [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2017914?tstart=0) by [Pondini](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2017914?tstart=0#9520364)

Answer (score 2):

Enable snapshots. In VMWare when a snapshot is created, the (VMDK) hard drive contents are frozen, while changes are stored as a separate delta.

Before: 
20GB VMDK + 1GB of changes = 20GB of changed files to backup

After
20GB VMDK (Snapshotted) + 1GB of changes = 1GB of changes to backup.

Additionally, you can keep snapshotting, so if you have an initial 20gb Snapshot1 + 2gb of deltas, each incremental backup would be 2gb.

Once you take a second snapshot, you end up with 22gb frozen. 20GB for S1, 2GB for S2, and then you just need to backup the next deltas.

The only downsides are:

1. It takes more physical space. 20GB frozen image + 2gb of deltas take a total of 22gb of storage.
2. It's not possible to shrink snapshotted VMs, so make sure to pre-shrink before taking the snapshot.

Comment: Be careful, snapshots tend to reduce performance, so try to keep as few as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say *"changes made to the VM don't matter"* then you can do what I do which is

1. Put all the VMs in one folder
2. Exclude the folder with the VMs from Time Machine
3. Manually back up the VM folder.  I keep a copy offsite on a portable RAID 1 drive.

Letting Time Machine "do its thing" is a **bad** idea, as it will make a new copy every it does a backup, which is generally around once an hour.  You will eat up all your storage space very quickly and it will be pointless anyway.

You could *"backup the VM using time machine once, then exclude the folder that contains all the VMs"* but the Time Machine interface is not the best for retrieving your saved copy in that situation, plus Time Machine will delete old files if it needs to in order to save space and you don't know when it will delete your one and only backup copy of your VM.

By doing a manual backup of your VMs you can also refresh them once in a while (say when new guest OS updates are applied) much more easily than with a Time Machine solution.

Snapshots affect performance quite a bit unless the snapshot and the virtual disk is on a high-performance solid-state drive.  It is worth considering if you need regular backups of ongoing work on the VM, but since you say you don't care about changes to the VM then snapshots are best avoided altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is kind of old, but I just wanted to share with you guys my experience. I hope this helps.

Basically I needed to truly understand how the snapshots worked, and if I could rely on them in case I ever needed to restore a VM from a snapshot using TimeMachine (and the snapshots). In other words, I had several unanswered questions and Parallels documentation is just not good enough.

So, here it goes...

First, disclaimer: I do **not** work for Parallels and I am in no way, shape, or form the final authority on the software. I did do extensive testing though, and the results of all my testing, which involved going through several iterations of waiting for snapshots to be automatically created, and test recovering the VM several times using TimeMachine, at different stages (with no snapshot yet taken, with 1 snapshot taken, with two, and more snapshots taken, with both the VM powered on and off), **and**, yes, my TimeMachine drive **is** encrypted.

I'll first give you the bottom line of all my testing, and then I will expand.

Bottom line: Yes. It all works. Perfectly. Seamlessly.

In an Apple philosophy kind of way, they say, this is all you need to know... As in, Apple (and in this case Parallels) says you do not need to know, so you do not need to know. Of course, we The Users disagree. We DO need to know.

So, here's my expanded answer:

1. I **do** have my backup drive encrypted! It's just the right thing to do.
2. Now, on to how SmartGuard Snapshots actually do work really well with TimeMachine... I thoroughly tested each and every single scenario I mention here:
   a) If there aren't yet any SmartGuard snapshots of the VM: TimeMachine backs up the entire .pvm file, however large it is, regardless of whether the VM is powered on or not. Again, if you have the backup drive encrypted, you are safe, even with the VM powered on.

   b) If there is already 1 SmartGuard snapshot, **and** TimeMachine has at least one full backup of the entire .pvm file, **then** it keeps the full .pvm backup, does not back it up again, and backs up the snapshot.

   c) If there is already 1 SmartGuard snapshot, **but** TimeMachine never had a chance to back up the entire .pvm, **then** it backs up the full .pvm, AND then it backs up the snapshot.

   d) And the pattern repeats itself... If there are 2 or more SmartGuard snapshots, TimeMachine will back up the full .pvm file only if it wasn't backed up before, and it will do the same for any SmartGuard snapshots that it hasn't yet backed up. That is, if the snapshot has already been backed up before, it is already backed up, and it is not backed up again. But any new snapshots that weren't yet backed up WILL be backed up. However many (non-backed up) snapshots there are.

If you follow my reasoning 1 thru 2, a thru d, you see that everything gets backed up, quite efficiently, without data duplication.

Now you may ask (I did!): "Ok. How does the restore work?" That was my main question because I wanted to make sure I could rely on SmartGuard and TimeMachine configured this way. It is quite simple, actually. When/If you want to restore, you simply enter TimeMachine, browse to the folder that contains the .pvm file, and click "Restore". TimeMachine/Parallels SmartGuard will automatically calculate which SmartGuard Snapshot was the closest one taken prior to the TimeMachine backup and restore the main first full .pvm backup, and then apply the latest SmartGuard Snapshot, which will bring your machine to the closest state it was in, when the last snapshot was taken, before the last backup was taken, for the date that you choose.

Practical example:

1. TimeMachine runs and backs up your entire .pvm, say, 01/01/2030.
2. SmartGuard takes a snapshot 01/02/2030.
3. TimeMachine runs and backs up the 01/02/2030 snapshot on 01/03/2030.
4. SmartGuard takes a snapshot 01/04/2030.
5. TimeMachine runs and backs up the 01/04/2030 snapshot on 01/05/2030.
6. SmartGuard takes a snapshot 01/06/2030.
7. At this point, on 01/07/2030, you experience a catastrophic failure of your drive and you lose the .pvm completely.
8. After resolving the problem with the drive, you enter TimeMachine, and browse to the folder where the .pvm file resides. Go back in time to 01/06/2030, and you click restore. TimeMachine knows it has a good full backup of the .pvm from the first original backup, and it also knows that the latest available backed-up SmartGuard Snapshot for the date you chose (01/06/2030) is from 01/04/2030. It restores the .pvm file exactly as it was as of 01/04/2030, which is the latest good backup/SmartGuard Snapshot combination per the restore date chosen.

I know I typed a book here. (And I am not the best writer :-)) But I hope I explained everything.

P.S. As someone mentioned, yes, there is a cost to running a VM with snapshots. But, if your machine is powerful enough, it should be no problem. I have done so for years, with no issues. (Running an iMac Pro here, and all other related specs also leave plenty of room for everything to breathe!)